# Extracting the Axis a Quaternion is rotating around from the Quaternion itself Directly

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations, quaternions

Quaternion has components X, Y, Z, and W.
If you created a Quaternion with input being a 3D Vector representing the axis (X,Y,Z) and a floating point number representing the amount to rotate around that axis(W). Can you extract the X,Y, and Z components used to construct the Quaternion from the Quaternion itself.

I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to extract the **original axis** from the Quaternion which has already been multiplied by itself several times. (So the axis internally never changes from the input axis actually) As in, the amount I want to rotate around the axis that I initially stored in the Quaternion is no longer inside but the axis remains.

I am **not** looking for any solution that requires converting the Quaternion itself to a different representation first, like a Rotation Matrix.

Can this be done or does the 4D nature of Quaternions not allow this?

If this helps...

When creating the Quaternion you would do...

```
QUATERNION( const VECTOR<Q> &axis, const Q &angle )
{       
     Q a = angle / 2;
     Q sin_a = sin( a );
     this->w = cos( a );
     this->x = axis.x * sin_a;
     this->y = axis.y * sin_a;
     this->z = axis.z * sin_a;
     this->Normalize(); 
}

 void Normalize()
 {  
     Q m = ( x *x + y * y + z * z + w * w );

      if( m < 0.991 || m > 1.001 )
      {
          m = sqrt( m );
          x = x / m;
          y = y / m;
          z = z / m;
          w = w / m;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Simply normalize the 'purely imaginary' (XYZ) part of the quaternion and that will return the axis.

Answer (score 5):

You can just read it directly. The pure quaternion part of the unit rotation quaternion is of the form $\sin(\theta/2)u$ where $u$ has unit length as a 3-vector and is the axis of rotation. Just normalize the pure quaternion part and you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Every quaternion  $z=a+\mathbf{i}b+\mathbf{j}c+\mathbf{k}d=a+\mathbf{v}$ can be expressed in exponential (polar) form as:
$$
z = |z|\left(\cos \theta +\mathbf{n}\sin \theta \right)=|z| e^ {\mathbf{n} \theta}= e^{\ln |z| + \mathbf{n} \theta}
$$
with:
$$
\begin{cases}
& |z|= \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2} \qquad|\mathbf{v}|=\sqrt{b^2+c^2+d^2} \\
& \cos \theta=\dfrac{a}{|z|} \qquad \sin \theta=\dfrac{|\mathbf{v}|}{|z|}\\
& \mathbf{n}=\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{|z|\sin \theta}=\dfrac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf v|}
\end{cases}
$$
If $z$ is a unitary quaternion than we have $|z|=1$ and $\mathbf n$ is the versor of the of the axis of a rotation of angle $2\theta$ represented, for a vector $\mathbf{x}$ ( that is a pure imaginary quaternion) by the product:
$$
R_{\mathbf{n},2\theta}(\mathbf{x})=e^ {\mathbf{n} \theta}\mathbf{x}e^ {-\mathbf{n} \theta}
$$

Since rotations around the same axis commutes, if you have a quaternion that represents $n$ rotations of angle $2\theta$ around the same axis, you can use this method to extract the axis $\mathbf{n}$.